# TextEditingController not passing text into named parameters

Tags: flutter

I am really struggling to understand why my code isn't working. I'm trying to pass the text from two controllers into another widget with named parameters which writes to Firebase.

My "Test" button properly prints both _titleController.text and _descriptionController.text

```
TextButton(
                    onPressed: (){
                      print(_titleController.text); //works fine
                      print(_descriptionController.text); //works fine
                    },
                    child: Text('test')
                ),
```

However when I pass these into my next widget it's blank! If I hardcore strings into these parameters it works properly:

```
PushNewE3 (
                 changeTitle: _titleController.text, //does not work (empty)
                 changeDescription: _descriptionController.text, //does not work (empty)
                )
```

Full code:

```
class CreateE3 extends StatefulWidget {
  const CreateE3({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CreateE3State createState() => _CreateE3State();
}

class _CreateE3State extends State<CreateE3> {
  final _titleController = TextEditingController();
  final _descriptionController = TextEditingController();


  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    _titleController.addListener(_printLatestValue);
  }

  @override
  void dispose(){
    _titleController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _printLatestValue(){
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('So Frustrating'),
      ),

      body: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Container(
            width: 800,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Text('Originator: **Add Current User**')      ,
                TextField(
                  maxLength: 40,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    labelText: 'Change Title'
                  ),
                  controller: _titleController,
                  onEditingComplete: (){
                    //_title = _titleController.text;
                  },
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0,10,0,0),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    maxLines: 5,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: 'Detailed Description'
                    ),
                    controller: _descriptionController,
                  ),
                ),
                TextButton(
                    onPressed: (){
                      print(_titleController.text); //successfully prints
                      print(_descriptionController.text); //successfully prints

                    },
                    child: Text('test')
                ),
                PushNewE3 (
                 changeTitle: _titleController.text, //DOES NOT WORK (empty)
                 changeDescription: _descriptionController.text, //DOES NOT WORK (empty)
                ) 

              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),

    );
  }
}



class PushNewE3 extends StatelessWidget {
  final String changeTitle;
  final String changeDescription;

  PushNewE3({
    required this.changeTitle,
    required this.changeDescription
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Create a CollectionReference called users that references the firestore collection
    CollectionReference notificationsE3 = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('notificationsE3');

    Future<void> pushNewE3() {
      // Call the notifications CollectionReference to add a new E3 notification
      return notificationsE3
          .add({
        //'originator': FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser,
        'changeTitle': changeTitle,
        'changeDescription': changeDescription,
      })
          .then((value) => print("E3 Created"))
          .catchError((error) => print("Failed to create E3: $error"));
    }

    return TextButton(
      onPressed: (){
        print('start:');
        print(changeTitle);
        print(changeDescription);
        print('-end');

      },
      child: Text(
        "Create E3",
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

EDIT:
I still don't understand why the above code doesn't work. I refactored my code into a single widget and now it's working. If anyone can explain why I would still appreciate understanding as there is clearly a gap in my knowledge.

If anyone in the future runs into the same problem here is the refactored code:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'main.dart';

var global = 'blank';

class CreateE3 extends StatefulWidget {
  const CreateE3({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CreateE3State createState() => _CreateE3State();
}

class _CreateE3State extends State<CreateE3> {
  final _titleController = TextEditingController();
  final _descriptionController = TextEditingController();


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Create a CollectionReference called users that references the firestore collection
    CollectionReference notificationsE3 = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('notificationsE3');

    Future<void> pushNewE3() {
      // Call the notifications CollectionReference to add a new E3 notification
      return notificationsE3
          .add({
        //'originator': FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser,
        'changeTitle': _titleController.text,
        'changeDescription': _descriptionController.text,
      })
          .then((value) => print("E3 Created"))
          .catchError((error) => print("Failed to create E3: $error"));
    }

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(_titleController.text),
      ),

      body: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Container(
            width: 800,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Text('Originator: **Add Current User**')      ,
                TextField(
                  maxLength: 40,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                      labelText: 'Change Title'
                  ),
                  controller: _titleController,
                  onChanged: (text){
                    setState(() {

                    });
                  },

                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0,10,0,0),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    maxLines: 5,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: 'Detailed Description'
                    ),
                    controller: _descriptionController,
                  ),
                ),
                TextButton(
                    onPressed: (){
                      pushNewE3();
                    },
                    child: Text('SAVE')
                ),

              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),

    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in the onPressed To pass a value and show it, you have to use setState(() { _myState = newValue; });

Something like this

```
TextButton(
                onPressed: (){
                  print(_titleController.text);
                  print(_descriptionController.text);
                  setState(() { _myNewText = _titleController.text; });

                },
                child: Text('test')
            ),
```

Comment: That button is working as coded, the controller.text prints fine. I've tried calling setState and writing the controller to a new variable but that doesn't work either. 

I have also tried controller.addListener(_updateValues) and again it will print in real time but the variable will not pass as named parameters

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what are you trying to do exactly but here's what I did:
1 - add a local variable _title
2 -  add this code to the onPressed function:

```
setState(() { 
             _title= _titleController.text; 
            });
```

This is the whole code :

```
  class CreateE3 extends StatefulWidget {
     const CreateE3({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
     @override
    _CreateE3State createState() => _CreateE3State();
  }

  class _CreateE3State extends State<CreateE3> {
    final _titleController = TextEditingController();
    final _descriptionController = TextEditingController();
    String _title = 'So Frustrating';


   @override
    void initState(){
    super.initState();
   }

  @override
   void dispose(){
   _titleController.dispose();
   super.dispose();
  }


 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
     appBar: AppBar(
       title: Text(_title),
     ),

    body: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Container(
          width: 400,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Text('Originator: **Add Current User**')      ,
              TextField(
                maxLength: 40,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    labelText: 'Change Title'
                ),
                controller: _titleController,
                onEditingComplete: (){
                  //_title = _titleController.text;
                },
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0,10,0,0),
                child: TextFormField(
                  maxLines: 5,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                      labelText: 'Detailed Description'
                  ),
                  controller: _descriptionController,
                ),
            ),
              TextButton(
                  onPressed: (){
                    print(_titleController.text);
                    print(_descriptionController.text);
                    setState(() {
                      _title = _titleController.text;
                    });

                  },
                  child: Text('test')
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        ],
      ),

    );
   }
 }
```

.........................
so this is when you first start the app :

[image]

after changing the TextField and pressing the 'test button the title in the appbar change :

[image]

Comment: I seem to have worded my problem poorly, only put the "test" button there to verify the controller.text did indeed contain a value. I am trying to take the controller.text and pass it PushNewNotification() that writes it to Firebase. I tried making a global variable and calling setSet from the test button and even this fails to move anything into PushNewNotification.